# change MySQL to special value for accepted by bot telegram

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use keyboard in telegram BOT by PHP.
i read from database as array :

```
$tryme = Array([0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D [4] => E)
```

i need a out put like this :

```
$output = [['A'],['B'],['C'],['D'],['E']];
```

i used json_encode also but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It´s quite simple: Just iterate over the `tryme` array and wrap the values in another array.

```
  $tryme = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($tryme); $i++) {

    $tryme[$i] = [$tryme[$i]];

  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much , Perfect.